# Colouring a tetrahedron with 4 colours

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

The group action is Rotation (1 2)(3 4).

Then if I have a colouring fixed by (1 2)(3 4) then why do faces 123 and and 124 have to be coloured the same colour?

And why do faces 134 and 234 have to be coloured with the same colour?
What does it mean for the tetrahedron to be fixed by (1 2)(3 4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permuataion $(12)(34)$ turns the tetrahedron $180^\circ$ around. It makes the $123$ face go to the $124$ face (or actually, the $214$ face) and vice versa, and it makes the $134$ face go to the $243$ face (and vice versa). Therefore, a colouring that is *fixed* by this permutation means that you cannot, just by the colouring, tell the difference between before and after. That means that the faces that swap places must be the same colour.

In the same way, we can analyse the permutation $(123)$. Then the $123$-face remains the same (or it becomes the face $231$, if that's important to you), but the faces $124, 234, 314$ cycle around. That means that the colourings that are fixed by this operation is any one that has whatever colour on the $123$ face, but where the three faces $124, 234$ and $314$ all have the same colour (which might be the same as the $123$ face, or it might not).

Comment: So if you were looking at the rotation ( 2 3 4). Then faces 124, 123, 134 have to be coloured the same and the face 234 have to be coloured the different colour so we have two colours?